# ImageMagick mogrify doesn't work

Tags: batch-file, imagemagick, mogrify

This works:

```
convert 005_R.JPG -fuzz 20% -fill white -opaque "#eceaeb" 005_R_magic.JPG
```

.. but this doesn't:

```
mogrify * -fuzz 20% -fill white -opaque "#eceaeb"
```

what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Put the file names to process at the end:

```
mogrify -fuzz 20% -fill white -opaque "#eceaeb" *
```